# ArrayList.AddRange is not allowing to add another array

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

While I'm trying to add an arrayList2 to Another ArraList1 (ArraList1 is Nothing) through AddRange Method, it is throwing:

> NUllUnhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>    not set to an instance of an object

```vb
Private Sub Fun1(ByVal ArrayList2 As ArrayList)

    Dim ArraList1 As ArrayList = ViewState("Details")

      ArraList1.AddRange(ArrayList2 )
```

Please let me know how to fix this one. Even tried with add function. but no luck.

```
ArraList1.Add(ArrayList2 )
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use ArrayLists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough context shown in the question to be 100% here, but I'm 97% certain that there's nothing in `ViewState("Details")` at the time this code runs. You need an object instance before you can act on any properties of the object. If it's normally or okay that `ViewState("Details")` is empty at this point, you need to check for it and create the object:

```
Dim ArraList1 As ArrayList = ViewState("Details")
If ArraList1 Is Nothing Then ArraList1 = New ArrayList()
'Don't forget to assign this back to the ViewState. Or better yet, avoid needing to keep lists in memory.
```

Also, don't use ArrayLists, and don't store lots of information (like large collections) in the ViewState.